# Images not being rounded in UIStackView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uistackview

I'm trying to round several images and add them in a stack view, for some reason it's not working. Basically, I have an array with all `UIImage` names and assign them to a `UIImageView`. When I try to make a circle out of the image, it's not working :

```
 var navStackView : UIStackView = {
    let stack = UIStackView()
    stack.axis = .horizontal
    stack.alignment = .center
    stack.distribution = .fillEqually
   // stack.spacing = -10
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return stack
}()

var images = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let navController = navigationController!

    navController.navigationBar.addSubview(navStackView)
    // x, y, w, h
    navStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navController.navigationBar.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    navStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navController.navigationBar.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    navStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navController.navigationBar.topAnchor).isActive = true
    navStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navController.navigationBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


    for image in images {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.height / 2
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
     //   imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        navStackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)

        navStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    navigationItem.titleView = navStackView
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
var once = true
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  if once {
     navStackView.subviews.forEach { $0.layer.cornerRadius = $0.frame.height / 2 }
     once = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be called everytime subviews are laid out? Wouldn't that be inefficient if it called for other view operations happening in the view controller?

Comment: yes, it is and for that i always recommend once var inside **viewDidLayoutSubviews** if he has to use it

Comment: That seems like a bad approach to me.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri this approach is commonly known I didn't create it  , plus your code forces layouting the stackview every run of loop , so do you think that also good ???